# Archived app shows no window content, it works fine when running it on Xcode

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am writing an OSX app with Xcode. 
It consists of 1 Window controller which contains view of View Controller. 
Window Controller and View Controller are linked each other through a `Relationship "window content" to "View Controller"`.

ViewController has 1 NSView as it's view, and it contains NSSplitView and NSBox as it's children.

This app works fine on Xcode, and show view really well when I run it on Xcode.

But after I archived it, and export on Xcode Organizer, The app doesn't show any content, it only shows ToolBar.

Comment: Check what is in archive (show package content) and compare it to debug app content bundle

Comment: great idea, i checked the package content, and fixed it. it was using WebKit and AVKit, i added the frameworks to the linked library, and it works fine now.

Comment: I had the same issue, mine was missing AVKit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on the archived app file.
2. Show package contents
3. Contents -> MacOS
4. You will see a binary file that has same name as your app.
5. Launch the app, it will show Terminal, and it gives you what's wrong with the binary.
6. after you fix all problems that the terminal shows, the app will work normally.